# Internationalization override on Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, rails-i18n

I installed the `spree_i18n` gem to support multi-language on my Spree ecommerce.
I need to translate some strings differently from the originally provided translation, as well as adding some extra strings in various locales.
How may I proceed?

Comment: Overriding locale keys (i.e. adding to your app `config/locales/en.yml` or whichever language you want) should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @zrl3dx said, it's enough to override locale keys (i.e. adding to your app config/locales/en.yml or whichever language you want).